# Is there a lightweight Java code metrics analyser that I can run in eclipse with Maven, Jenkins/Hudson?

Tags: java, maven, hudson, jenkins, metrics

I know about [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) but I'd rather not (actually, can't) run a whole web app that says it likes 500Mb of ram just to run some reports on a build. I've already got Checkstyle, FindBugs & PMD - can I  configure them for the kind of metrics I'm looking for ... method length, class length, mccabe  etc.? I'd also like to see (in jenkins) graphing of these over time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[eclipse-cs](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) is a checkstyle plug-in for eclipse which can report on your custom checkstyle file.  This can be used to setup metric checking for method length, class length, cyclomatic complexity and much more.  I always run my eclipse setup with this enabled as it gives great real-time metrics.

PMD, checkstyle and findbugs all offer trending reports in their plugins for your Hudson/Jenkins build process to see trending over time.  It should be an option near the bottom of your configuration on your build.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into configuring checkstyle for these metrics.

Comment: These should get you started: [Method Length](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#MethodLength), [Class Length](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#FileLength), [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_metrics.html#CyclomaticComplexity) and [everything else](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html)

Comment: I've had a look at these and can configure the warnings as I like but haven't found a way of plotting these (individually) over time. Is this possible? What I'd really like is a view of these metrics over time, by package ... maybe Sonar is the only option here.

Comment: See [this](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449305352/chapter-code-quality.html) for setting up hudson with checkstyle.  It can definitely show you your trends over time.  See figure 8.13 for example.  It should be relatively straight-forward.

Answer (score 3):

[Crap4J](http://www.crap4j.org/) offers cyclomatic complexity and, of course, [CRAP](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2011/02/this-code-is-crap.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's a [JavaNCSS](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javancss-maven-plugin/) Maven plugin that does a lot of metrics stuff.

There's a Jenkins plugin that's supposed to generate graphs for visualization, but I was never able to get it to work.

BTW, you can also check out the [core JavaNCSS tool](http://javancss.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse you can take a look at the [Google Analytix plugin](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/javadevtools/download-codepro.html) or for Maven integration at [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the google plugin but I stated that sonar wasn't really an option.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a lightweight Java code metrics analyser that I can run in eclipse

You might want to check out http://www.eclemma.org/ or http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/ both of which I have had great sucess with in conjunction with Maven and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[ProjectCodeMeter](http://www.projectcodemeter.com) is around 5MB download which shows code flow complexity,SLOC,arithmetic complexity metrics and more, even estimated development time. it supports Java as well as other programming languages.